# How to install sshd on Mac?

Tags: macos, homebrew, sshd

I am trying to use Hadoop on my Mac, but it requires Java and `ssh`, so I need to install them.
I have already done the `ssh` part with the help of Homebrew, but after I download `sshd`, I don't know how to install it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 23):

OS X comes with **sshd**, you only need to enable it in **System Preferences**, under **Sharing** by clicking on **Remote Login**:

[image]

Comment: And BTW ssh is already there as well...

Comment: With Catalina... sshd is unconfigurable, as System is mounted in a readonly fashion...

Answer (score 2):

System Preferences -> Sharing -> Check "Remote Login"