# SSHD on OS X in Travis CI

Tags: macos, hadoop, ssh, travis-ci, sshd

I need SSHD (SSH server) enabled in order to make Hadoop running in my Travis CI job.

For Linux I just do `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` and it works. But for OS X the only tips I've found say to enable `Remote Login` in settings: [How to install sshd on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369172/how-to-install-sshd-on-mac)

How can I enable SSHD using just `.travis.yml` for OS X?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found the command to enable Remote Login from terminal:

```
sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on
```